# Downcasting in Java with new and same return type instance

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I know little about DownCasting and Upcasting but thing which is confusing me is below code.

Lets say I have a class Parent and Child extends this class

```
public class Parent {
public Parent methodA()
{
    System.out.println("Parent");
    return this;
}

}

public class Child extends Parent{

public void methodB()
{
    System.out.println("In Child");
}
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Parent p = new Child();
    Child c=(Child) p.methodA();
}
```

My confusion is In Parent Class methodA, if I return new instance of Parent then code throws run time exception but if i return the same instance, then why dont I get the error.

```
 public Parent methodA()
 {
    System.out.println("Parent");
    return new Parent(); // in this case downcasting throws error
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

If `p.methodA()` returns the same instance (i.e. p), it returns a `Child` instance (since p was assigned `new Child()`), which can safely be cast to `Child`.

If, however, `p.methodA()` returns a new `Parent` instance, that instance is not a `Child`, and it cannot be cast to a `Child`.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `p` actually holds a `Child` and calls `methodA()` on a `Child`, which inherits `methodA()` from `Parent`. So `this` will be of type `Child` in this case.

But if you return a `Parent` (new or not does not matter), it is not possible to cast it to a `Child` since it is not a child.

Answer (score 1):

When you say `return this;` you're sending back a pointer to an object in memory. The return type specified on the method signature is telling to the caller that the object returned is "viewable" as `Parent` object (in other words with the interface declared by `Parent` class definition). Now, when you calls p.methodA() it still returns a `this` reference, it is still viewable as `Parent` object but it is also a `Child` object: so you won't have any problems in upcasting to `Child`.

In second implementation you're explicitly returning a new instance of `Parent` object...which **isn't a `Child`**, so you'll have a `ClassCastException`